# How to remove label of the json data using fluentd out webhdfs

Tags: json, hadoop, fluent

I am using fluentd out_webhdfs to post data into hadoop hdfs
td-agent.conf:

```
<match access.**>
  type webhdfs
  host hadoop1
  port 50070
  path /data/access.log.%Y%m%d_%H.log
  output_data_type ltsv
  field_separator TAB
  output_include_tag false
</match>
```

using curl command to post data:

```
curl -X POST -d 'json={"name":"abc","id":"8754738"}' http://localhost:8888/.access
```

the result in hdfs file is below:

```
2014-08-20T08:25:28Z name:abc id:8754738
```

**Is there any way to remove the "name:" and "id:" out** , the result I want is :

```
2014-08-20T08:25:28Z abc 8754738
```

Any body help me please !

Comment: I had resolved it , use the 'attr:name,id' and remove line 'output_data_type ltsv' in td-agent.conf